# AJAX request returning error

Tags: php, ajax

I have an AJAX request that is throwing an error.

It's part of a larger system that I've inherited, so I can't post the files in their entirety, but I've tried to isolate the relevant code:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url: ajax_url, // Valid URL
        data: jsonData, // Valid JSON
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: POST, 
        async:true, 
        success: function(data) 
        {
            console.log(data);
            parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(parsedData);
            // Here I am trying to log successful output
        },
        error: function(jsonData) 
        {
            console.log("error");
            console.log(jsonData);
        }
    });
```

In the PHP, values are added to an array and returned:

```
$data['status']=200;
$data['new_id']=$insert_id;
return json_encode($data);
```

All I am logging at the moment is 'error'. Apologies again for incomplete code, I have tried to supply the code where I think the error is caused.

Comment: What error is it throwing? Is the JSON syntactically correct?

Comment: If you thought you can fetch the "error" result from php with error: function() you gone wrong ... the response willl be success and in success function you have to check if data is error or success from serverside

Comment: setup proper header with header() function and use echo on json_encode

Comment: I agree with Robert, you need to echo the response, without echoing a response it will fail.

Comment: The JSON data is

{"line_1":"value","line_2":"value","line_3":"value","town":"value","county":"value","post_code":"value","country":"value"}. The only 'error report' I'm getting is the console logging 'error', which suggests that the success function isn't being touched?

Comment: Look at the developer tools in your browser. Check the Net tab. Make sure the request and response are formatted the way you expect.

Comment: Look at the definition of the error function in the jQuery API documentation: `Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )`. You've got three arguments there, the second two (which you are ignoring) are really useful for determining what went wrong.

Comment: I've had cases where the error function always gets called because the returned data is not in the proper format. Try removing the `dataType:'json'` attribute.